# Detect device type with UI Automation

Tags: javascript, ios, automation, ios-ui-automation

I am using [ui-screen-shooter](https://github.com/jonathanpenn/ui-screen-shooter), which makes use of the [UI Automation JavaScript API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html) to take screenshots of apps. My app has a slightly different structure on iPad and iPhone, so I need to detect the device type in my `shoot_the_screen.js` script and run different code. I would like something equivalent to `[[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]` that I can use in JavaScript. Here is the best I have come up with. It works, but do you know of a cleaner, less device-dependent way to get the same information?

```js
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();

var width = target.rect().size.width;

if (width == 1024 || width == 768)
{
    // iPad
}
else
{
    // iPhone
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `model()` on the target to get the information you need. That's exactly what [I'm doing in the ui-screen-shooter](https://github.com/jonathanpenn/ui-screen-shooter/blob/master/automation/capture.js#L42) itself.

```
var modelName = UIATarget.localTarget().model();

// This prints "iPhone" or "iPad" for device. "iPhone Simulator" and "iPad Simulator" for sim.
UIALogger.logMessage(modelName);
```

Comment: It prints "iPhone Simulator" for me when I’m running in the simulator.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. You can do `var isPhone = target.model().match(/iPhone/);` and it will be equal to either `iPhone` or `null`.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Should have mentioned it. I'll update the answer.